Efficient "pseudo-continuous" convolution in PyTorch
I have a set of N finely sampled 1D functions in a tensor of shape (N, B), that I want to convolve with a response function and resample on a coarser set of points, yielding a tensor of shape (N, A). Unfortunately, my case has a few problems that prevent me from using torch.nn.functional.conv1d:

The coarse sampling points are not necessarily integer multiples of the fine sampling points, although I might be able to nudge them a bit so they are.
The coarse sampling points are not evenly spaced. This, I cannot change.
Each function has its own predefined (i.e., fixed at the start of the program) set of coarse sampling points. The number of points is always the same, but the positions differ. Again, this is not something I can change.

The way I tackle it now is to create a tensor T of shape (N, A, B) with the response function, so that its components are something like T[n,a,b] = response(coarse(n, a)-fine(b)). This only needs to be done once. Then, every time I want to convolve and downsample a set of functions f, I simply use
torch.einsum("nab,nb->na", T, f)

Unfotunately, with N≈20, A≈500, and B≈50000, this seemingly trivial matrix multiplication is still pretty heavy, and it gets called very often, making it by far the greatest bottleneck in the program. So, I was wondering if anyone could think of a way to optimise this. I've already tried making T a sparse tensor (with T_sparse = T.to_sparse()) and using
torch.bmm(T_sparse, f.unsqueeze(-1)).squeeze(-1)

but this gives similar/slightly worse performance.
N.B.: T has a sparsity of about 97%. There are no tunable parameters here, but I would like to keep everything compatible with autograd.
